# How do paths change when calling a program from a script - Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, cmake, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently writing a bash script to launch a program (that I didn't write) after a USB is inserted. The script is called at the correct time, and there is no problem with the USB aspect. (I only mention this because everything works fine if the script is called from terminal)

Running a simple program (one that creates a file for example) is not a problem either.

The program I want to run is called with:

```
./configure
./bin/programName
```

This works fine from terminal.
In the script, I cd into the same directory I call from in terminal but it doesn't work.

```
cd /home/path
./configure &>> /home/path/log.text
./bin/programName &>> /home/path/log.text
```

The output of this (in log.text) is:

```
CMake Error: CMake executable cannot be found at /cmake
CMake Error: Error executing cmake::LoadCache(). Aborting.


(Program Name:14072): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed/troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which user is the script running as when you plug it in, and which do you run it as in your terminal?

Comment: The same (admin). I've tried all permutations of using sudo as well with the exact same results.

It may help to know that the project is currently being hosted on a git repository. Thus, the configure (and cmake) files are all in their own checked-out directory. However, as stated, this isn't a problem when the commands are directly ran from terminal: the program starts just fine.

Comment: I wonder if that empty string before `/cmake` is a variable that you have in your environment that does not exist when the script is triggered otherwise.

Comment: @glenn jackman, you very well may be correct. In configure, to create the cmake files, the line   (cd build >/dev/null 2>&1 && cmake .. "$@")   is used. This seems to be the problem, since the triggered script is trying to go to /cmake instead of /build/..

Any suggestions?